# Joomla 3 Custom Category Blog Page

Tags: joomla, categories

Hey everybody I'm trying to create a custom category page.

How do I loop through the subcategories of a parent category, and furthermore loop through the articles of those subcategories?

I have added a custom template in the /templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/category/blog.php, I am just unsure how to access the data I need to loop through.

Comment: A template override uses the same data that the core view template does. What's not working?

Comment: Look at `mod_articles_categories` and `mod_articles_category`

Comment: You have to be more specific. How is what you want different from a normal category view with subcategories included?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using JDBO to query the data I needed.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('table');
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```